# I am getting Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src' error while running ocr python file. Below attached is the full error message

Tags: ocr, opencv, python

it is working fine in my local system but when running from pythonanywhere.com, i am getting this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/clonesangram/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/home/clonesangram/.virtualenvs/django3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/clonesangram/django_projects/ocrsite/ocr/views.py", line 187, in image_upload_view
return render(request, 'ocr/index1.html', {'form': form, 'img_obj': img_obj, 'text': text_detector(image)})
File "/home/clonesangram/django_projects/ocrsite/ocr/Test_OCR_Img.py", line 15, in text_detector
image = cv2.resize(np.float32(image), (320, 320), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

Exception Type: TypeError at /ocr/upload/
Exception Value: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Comment: do you think there is a cv2 version problem coz I have run the same ocr code in local pycharm it is running fine but when i try to run it from pythonanywhere with web application I am getting this error.
I checked from my local pycharm and the current version I am using is 4.3.0. And in here(pythonanywhere) it is 4.5.1. So, there is a version difference.

Comment: It could be a version issue or it could be that, on PythonAnywhere, there might be some reason that you're passing different data into the function call. Check that the data you're passing in is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I updated the version the same as my local machine but still getting the same error message.
I am using the same image file. Do you think my images are getting corrupted if I am uploading them from web application and running the ocr python file in pythonanywhere.com?

Comment: the ocr python file is running fine separately if I run it from pythonanywehere.com but when I am running or calling it from django3 views the uploaded image file it is not able to recognize. This is my view: def image_upload_view(request): if request.method == 'POST': form = ImageForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid(): form.save()  img_obj = form.instance pic = Image.objects.filter(id=1).first()  str_path = pic.image.name path = Path(str_path)            return render(request, 'ocr/index1.html', {'form': form, 'img_obj': img_obj, 'text':text_detector(path)})

Comment: If it's working in one place an PythonAnywhere and not another, then you are running it in 2 different environments (Python version or virtualenv). Just make sure that you're running it the same way in your web app and whatever you mean by "separately"

Comment: According to [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/14077) that error can get raised when you pass a None in to certain OpenCV functions that are expecting an image.  So perhaps when you run the code in your web application, you're somehow accidentally passing a None into one of the functions?